# instantiate all sub classes along with the parent class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Let's say I have a class that looks like this:

```
    private class CompanyPerson
    {
        public Person Person { get; set; }
        public string UserTokenGuid { get; set; }
    }
```

And then `Person` looks like this:

```
    private class Person
    {
        public Info Info { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        ....
    }
```

And `Info`...

```
    private class Info 
    {
        ...
    }
```

Now, if I create an instance of `CompanyPerson`:

```
CompanyPerson companyPerson = new CompanyPerson();
```

That's all good.  But then if I immediadlty try this:

```
companyPerson.Person.FirstName = "Bob";
```

It throws an error because `companyPerson.Person` does not exist. I get that, and I understand why. But, this is a deep class with sub-classes that go 8 or 9 deep.  Is there some way to instantiate all of the sub classes along with the parent class?

Comment: Instantiate them in the constructor?  So `CompanyPerson` constructor has `Person  = new Person();`

Comment: or set a default on the property: `public Person Person { get; set; } = new Person();`

Comment: I've run into some issues with this with deserializing responses, which can leave a property null even with the default serializer (e.g., the property wasn't even on the response being deserialized, so it left it null).

Comment: What if there are multiple types possible for a given property? Which one should be used then?

Comment: I´m voting to close this question as far too broad. In particular it misses the context why OP needs this, e.g. is it for testing? What is the structure of the data? Just data-objects? Abstract classes/interfaces?...

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no generic way to instantiate "all child objects".

You may reflect over all properties to find them (including recursive walk), but actually creating objects is not generally possible.

Why:

- some types may not have accessible constructors or no default constructor. Thus even if you know exact type of the property you could not instantiate it even via reflection
- some properties can be of interface type. There is no way to magically know what actual type should be used.
- there could be multiple types deriving from type of the property - again, no way to know what type should be used.
- some properties can be read-only and could not be set outside of the class (like `IList<int> Foo {get; private set;}`)
- some properties actually should refer to same object which could not be described in any declarative way (`MyType SecondInArray {get;set;}`)

In some cases you can use dependency injection container to instantiate types you interested in (after using reflection to find all properties). But really there is nothing better than actually setting all properties in constructors.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to instantiate new instances of each nested member as they appear like so...

```
var companyPerson = new CompanyPerson 
{
    Person = new Person 
    {
        Info = new Info
        {
            // Keep instantiating nested properties as they appear
        },
        FirstName = "Bob",
        LastName = "Doe"
    },
    UserTokenGuid = "someValue"
};
```

It can get a little hairy but that's the best way I can think to do it in one run instead of instantiating one nested object at a time.

My experience with this is from building deeply nested DTO models that translate to JSON objects for Web Services.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is common during unit testing.
I don't know whether this is ever done in production, anyway you can create a stub (i.e. initialize a dummy instance of your class, properties included) using any testing framework; my favorite is NSubtitute, you just have to do this:

```
var APerson = Substitute.For<CompanyPerson>();
```

and you should be good to go.
Install it via NuGet:

```
Install-Package NSubstitute -Version 3.1.0
```

Comment: Umm, I think this is overengenering for such a simple problem. Also, how this will handle abstract classes/interfaces is just complete mystery or headache to setup in some configurator. I prefer not to use it this way, even for unit testing - you will test error prone code, but your code can be not prone to errors at all.

Comment: @eocron Interfaces and abstract classes can be  mocked easily using a mocking-framework such as NSubstitute. That´s the whole purpose of them.

Comment: And why he should use mocking in production code? This is just doesn't make sense.

Comment: I think it's actually under-engineering, a one-liner and that's it. Personally I'd like to initialize everything in a controlled way in production, but if things are too complicated I understand it may feel like a chore.

Comment: @eocron Francesco clearly states that this purpose is used in unit-testing.

Comment: @eocron did he say it was in production? Plus, verbatim from my answer: "I don't know whether this is ever done in production"